# Seaside & jQuery UI: Sortable list not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, pharo, seaside

Beginner here.
I'm currently trying to learn Seaside, and how to integrate jQuery with it.  I've been trying to implement some of the examples provided in the Seaside jQuery UI Functional Test Suite in my own image.

For some reason, I can't get a sortable list to work. I copy & pasted the code from the example but it doesn't work.  I have made sure to add the jQuery library, and have tested that it works with a clickable animated heading.  But my sortable list just gets rendered with no interaction.

Inspecting the page source does reveal an error message: "TypeError: undefined is not a function(...)", but I don't understand what this means?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I want to get the hang of this and need to understand why it's not working.  See my code below, as copied exactly from their example, with the exception of assigning a list to the items variable:

```
| items |
    items := OrderedCollection newFrom: {'peas' . 'carrots' . 'beetroot'}.
   html unorderedList
      script: (html jQuery new sortable
         onStop: (html jQuery ajax
            callback: [ :values | items := values ]
            passengers: (html jQuery this find: 'li')));
      with: [
         items do: [ :each |
            html listItem
               class: 'ui-corner-all';
               passenger: each;
               with: each ] ]
```

And including the jQuery code as rendered in the browser:

```
function onLoad() {
        $("#id3").sortable({              <-- TypeError occurs here
            "stop": function() {
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "/jquery",
                    "data": ["_s=To5SuUU8YuW_HSjD", "_k=MpvlOw_BWjmgF9Uy", "1", "2=" + encodeURIComponent($.map($(this).find("li").get(), function(each) {
                        return each.id
                    }).join(","))].join("&")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you also add the jQueryUI library? I would think the 'sortable' is not found on a jQuery... so it probably is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not realise that jQuery UI is not part of the jQuery library.  Sorry for the dumb question! It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things to remark.

1. `sortable` (`JQSortable` class) comes with jQuery UI, so first be sure to include the jQuery UI library in your Seaside application (e.g. `JQUiDevelopmentLibrary`).
2. The `items` variable is a method temporary variable, so it will always have new items in that order. It should be an instance variable (but I guess you did it so for the purpose of this Stack Overflow example).
3. The `this` object in the ajax function doesn't refer to the list element anymore. I added an id to the `<ul>` tag (`id: 'list'`) and I'm referencing such jQuery object from within the JS object passed to the `onStop:` handler.

With these changes I could make it work.

```
renderContentOn: html
    items := items
        ifNil: [ OrderedCollection newFrom: {'peas' . 'carrots' . 'beetroot'} ].
    html unorderedList
        id: 'list';
        script:
            (html jQuery new sortable
                onStop:
                    (html jQuery ajax
                        callback: [ :values | items := values ]
                        passengers: ((html jQuery id: 'list') find: 'li')));
        with: [ items
                do: [ :each | 
                    html listItem
                        class: 'ui-corner-all';
                        passenger: each;
                        with: each ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks as well. It's useful to know that the list should be an instance variable as opposed to a temp one, makes sense.  Like I said, major beginner here still.   Thanks again!

Comment: I have a follow up question... when using the sortable function in a different application, after rearranging the list items, when I save or refresh the page, the list items get cleared? How can I keep this from happening?

Comment: The items is an OrderedCollection object, so it will depend how you store/retrieve such collection. With your original example the collection was created everytime the component was rendered, with my example the collection (and its order) will be preserved for the lifetime of the component, but will be different between different instances of the same component (and so within different user sessions).

This is more a persistence question than a Seaside one.